# One Time Pad Key Distribution

Tags: one-time-pad, key-distribution

For multiple OTP keys, why not do this:

Key = Hash[(EC)DH Shared Secret + Counter]

The counter will increase per message, and the output of the hash will be random for each new unique input into it. What are the problems or weaknesses with this design??

EDIT:
For clarification: both parties will have the shared secret from an ECDH exchange, random numbers from Pythons os.urandom for generating the ECC key

Comment: Are you really really sure that the output will be truly random (as required by the OTP definition), or just pseudo random?

Comment: The shared secret will be calculated from keys that were generated using pythons `os.urandom` function, and whilst not truly random, they are unseeded and generated from many different sources that are unpredictable. Hashing this shared secret will possibly slightly reduce the randomness.

Comment: You should clarify your scenario and your goal. Your question does not mention a source of randomness. And for symmetric encryption, both sides need to know the key. Key management (and it's transport) is the challenge - not the generation of the key. That's why OTP is often unsuitable for practical applications, even if the parties have access to TRNGs.

Comment: @tylo both parties will have the shared secret from the ECDH key exchange.

Comment: A key exchange does not give you true randomness - and that does not meet the requirements of OTP, so it is simply wrong to use that term. I still have no idea what your actual goal is. It seems to be added complexity for no reason at all - your communication is just as secure as the EC key exchange. Anything else is just added complexity and has exactly 0 impact on security. So what is your goal, and what is the benefit over just using the result of the key agreement directly?

Answer (score 3):

This principle is commonplace, it is a key derivation from a shared secret. The academic thing to do is to use a Key Derivation Function or a MAC where hash of a concatenation is used, perhaps
$$\operatorname{HMAC-Hash}\;[\;\text{Key}=\text{(EC)DH Shared Secret},\,\text{Message}=\text{Counter}\;]$$

We call the output a derived key, and it can be a one-use key.

I would not call it a One Time Pad key, even if it is used only once to mask some payload with XOR, because the usual assumption is that a One Time Pad (key) is truly random, and this is only pseudo-random.

Answer (score 2):

We call this idea a *key derivation function* (hashing the ECDH secret) for a *stream cipher* (expanding a short secret and a counter into a long pad).

**This idea is not problematic or weak; in fact, it is ubiquitous.**  For example, a part of the TLS protocol essentially works as follows:

1. Agree on an ECDH secret $s$.
2. Derive a session key $k = H(s)$ by hashing $s$, where $H$ is the TLS PRF with a particular label.
3. For the $i^{\mathit{th}}$ message, expand $k$ into a per-message pad $p_i = H'(k, i)$, where $H'$ is ChaCha or AES-CTR.
4. Encrypt the $i^{\mathit{th}}$ message $m_i$ with the ciphertext $c_i = m_i \oplus p_i$.
5. (Also authenticate the ciphertext with $k$ and $i$, because preventing forgery is practically always *at least* as important as keeping secrets.)

Of course, the security is only as good as the security of the ECDH system, the KDF, and the stream cipher—if you use a tiny curve and a hash function with a 32-bit pipe and RC4 as the stream cipher, it won't provide much security.

But if you use a reasonable choice like HKDF-SHA256 to hash an X25519 ECDH secret and use ChaCha/Poly1305 to encrypt and authenticate messages, you'll be fine—any security problems you have won't arise as a consequence of this construction.  You could even use HKDF-SHA256 to expand the secret into a long pad directly without ChaCha (but it wouldn't be very fast).

---

<sub>P.S.  There is a funny social phenomenon whereby you're not allowed to say the words ‘one-time pad’ in this context.  For some reason, the term ‘one-time pad’ is only allowed *either* for the idealized model $c_i = m_i \oplus p_i$ when the $p_i$ are exactly uniformly distributed, *or* for historical use of that model (however biased or reused the pad may have been historically)—it is never allowed when you use the model in modern cryptography as you just described with $p_i$ chosen as a pseudorandom function of a secret key, even though the modern notion of stream cipher is obviously inspired and justified by the security of the one-time pad model.</sub>

<sub>Only the term ‘one-time pad’ works like this; nobody bats an eye when a cryptographer studies an idealized model like $f(\cdots f(f(\mathit{iv}, m_1), m_2) \cdots, m_n)$ for uniform random $f$ and then instantiates it with $f = \operatorname{AES}_k$ but calls both the idealized model and the instantiation ‘CBC’—it is only forbidden to call the idealized model $c = m \oplus p$ instantiated with $p = \operatorname{AES}_k(0)$ a ‘one-time pad’.  Perhaps it's because cranks are attracted to red herrings like the value-laden name of the technical property [‘perfect secrecy’](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68606) of the one-time pad model, so obsession with one-time pads is a useful indicator for cranks.</sub>

Comment: @PaulUszak I addressed the matter of terminology in a footnote.  Satisfied?

Comment: The question was: _What are the problems and weaknesses in this design?_  The answer to that specific question is, as I said, that the design is not problematic or weak; security is as good as the components.

Comment: Kolmogorov randomness has nothing whatsoever to do with where keys come from; only [obscure corners of cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75457) involve Kolmogorov complexity at all, which is about the shortest program in a given language that prints a given string—not about an adversary's uncertainty surrounding what the string is, which is the point of a cryptographic key.

Comment: @PaulUszak Instead of just asserting that something is the case, it would be more productive to link to citations that support your claims or at least attempt at an explanation of why. Mathematics is about proof, not beliefs or assertions (you may not like it, but cryptography and our site *is* about mathematics). As-is, your comments don't help clear up any confusion, they simply create more by asserting an answer is wrong with no backup or explanation for your claim. Comments are intended to be used to help *improve the quality of answers*, not to haze the users that post them.

Answer (score -3):

The main problem is that it's not truly random, and therefore unsuitable for a real-by-definition one time pad. Addressing your comment which forms the crux:-

> The shared secret will be calculated from keys that were generated using pythons os.urandom function, and whilst not truly random, they are unseeded and generated from many different sources that are unpredictable.

Rewriting your formula, you have an iteration as $  k' = \text{HMAC}[  seed || c ]   $. Even without maths we can see that it's not truly random, as I just wrote it down algebraically. No matter how $seed$ is generated, it becomes fixed when incorporated into your formula.  You are then simply incrementing counter $c$. And as for *"each new unique input"*: Unique yes, but entirely predictable.

As $c$ increments, the cumulative output will become longer than the program that created it.  That breaks the fundamental definition of Kolmogorov randomness, and breaks the perfect secrecy paradigm of the one time pad.

When ever you describe the output of a OTP generating process, it must be longer, not shorter, than the pad itself. Even if only by a teensy-weensy little bit, like a print statement or full stop. It's another way of saying that you can't write down a OPT in algebraic terms. What you have is a mutually agreed upon pseudo random generator.

---

The Wikipedia article on [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) is pretty good.

Comment: Kolmogorov complexity is pretty much irrelevant to cryptography, and certainly not helpful here.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Let's make that your little secret...